# Excel Avg of Bins

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm looking to get the average pay that corresponds to a bin frequency count of pay variance from a target. I've used frequency formulas to get the distribution, but I cannot get the average values that go into the bins. How can I do this? Pref formula, VBA acceptable though.
Some of my formulas appear to be correctly getting what I want, but this is very manual and seems to contain errors (see the -100% bin with 5 freq count and an error for avg pay).
**Note that the second SUMIFS used for the average is counting a column of 1s used in other calcs, so it's similar to a COUNTIF.

```
        % Variance to Target    
   Chart 
   Freq   Avg Pay   Bins
    0     #DIV/0!   -150%
    0     #DIV/0!   -140%
    0     #DIV/0!   -130%
    0     #DIV/0!   -120%
    1     3.0375    -110%
    5     #DIV/0!   -100%
    4     17.85     -90%
    0     #DIV/0!   -80%
    3     200.2875  -70%
    11    1761.68   -60%
```

I'm using the following to try and calculate the average pay.

```
    =SUMIFS(Model!DG:DG,Model!DI:DI,"<-1.1",Model!DI:DI,">-1.2")
     /
     SUMIFS(Model!DQ:DQ,Model!DI:DI,"<-1.1",Model!DI:DI,">-1.2")
```

What I really want is a more automatic/dynamic formula than manually inputting each range for the test - a cell reference in the double quotes will just insert text as opposed to my bin values. e.g. SUMIFS(Model!DQ:DQ,Model!DI:DI,"EH2064").

Comment: You should temporarily add two additional cols, one for each `SUMIFS` of your avg formula - that way you easily see what you are using. Also, it would help, if you could be more specific about what your main question is here - how to get those `SUMIFS` right?

Comment: Thanks, I'd been going through the formulas via the Evaluate Formula tool, but still a good idea to split them out. editing main post for clarity.

Comment: Can you show some sample data and the result you want from it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved through the `=AVERAGEIF()` function.

For example written as follows:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(pay_range,variance_range,">="&bin1,variance_range,"<"&bin2),"")
```

This formula would have to be dragged over all rows corresponding to bins as shown in the screenshot here below.

[image: Conceptually reconstructed example]

This can also be done dynamically as an array formula by writing the following in only the first cell of the 'Avg Pay' data column:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(pay_range,variance_range,">="&lagged_bin_range,variance_range,"<"&bin_range),"")
```

which for the example shown in the screenshot above would be

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS($A$5:$A$1004,$B$5:$B$1004,">="&$F$4:$F$34,$B$5:$B$1004,"<"&$F$5:$F$35),"")
```

in cell E5 only. The rows below E5 will then automatically populate with the results.

The formula can furthermore be adjusted to also automatically adjust for the number of bins in the bin range by replacing `$F$4:$F$34` and `F$5:$F$35` by either `OFFSET($F$5,-1,0,COUNT($F:$F))` and `OFFSET($F$5,0,0,COUNT($F:$F))` or alternatively (for Excel 2021 or later) by `FILTER($F:$F,NOT(ISBLANK($F:$F)))` and `FILTER($F:$F,ISNUMBER($F:$F))` respectively.